# DynamodbDB query without a range key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have table defined with two column, column 1 is the `hash key` and column 2 is the `range key`.
I want to get all items defined with the same hash key (so the range key doesn't matter).

I tried to use the `new KeyPair().withHashKey(k)`. But it will throw exception saying that `no RANGE key value present`.

Is the only option I have is to do a scan for the table to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to use the `GetItem` call, which requires the complete key, and only returns one item. You need to use the `Query` call, and pass in a `KeyExpression` that only includes the partition key.